# Conditional join Pandas.Dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I try to partially join two dataframes :

```
import pandas
import numpy
entry1= pandas.datetime(2014,6,1)
entry2= pandas.datetime(2014,6,2)
df1=pandas.DataFrame(numpy.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[3,3]]), columns=['zick','zack'], index=[entry1, entry1, entry2, entry2])   
df2=pandas.DataFrame(numpy.array([[2,3],[3,3]]), columns=['eins','zwei'], index=[entry1, entry2])
```

I tried

```
df1 = df1[(df1['zick']>= 2) & (df1['zick'] < 4)].join(df2['eins'])
```

but this doesn't work. After joining values of df1['eins'] are expected to be [NaN,2,3,3].
How to do it? I'd like to it inplace without df copies.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? I have tried your code on 0.15.1 and it did work without any issues.

Comment: I use 0.14.0. together with Numpy 1.8.1 So maybe there is a bug in this version. If I update pandas only, might there arise any dependency issues?

Comment: I don't think updating pandas will raise any issue. [The docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/whatsnew.html#v0-15-0-october-18-2014) only warn about numpy being >=1.7.0.

Comment: Updated to 0.15.1 - still same problem after running the above code:             


First value third column of df1 should be NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you actually meant to use:

```
df1 = df1.join(df2['eins'])
mask = (df1['zick']>= 2) & (df1['zick'] < 4)
df1.loc[~mask, 'eins'] = np.nan
df1
```

yielding:

```
            zick  zack  eins
2014-06-01     1     1   NaN
2014-06-01     2     2     2
2014-06-02     3     3     3
2014-06-02     3     3     3
```

Issue you were having is that you were joining filtered dataframe, and not the original one, there was no place for `NaN` to appear (every cell was satisfying your filter).

EDIT:

Considering new inputs in the comments below, here is another approach.

Create an empty column that will need to be updated with values from second dataframe:

```
df1['eins'] = np.nan
print df1
print df2

            zick  zack  eins
2014-06-01     1     1   NaN
2014-06-01     2     2   NaN
2014-06-02     3     3   NaN
2014-06-02     3     3   NaN

            eins  zwei
2014-06-01     2     3
2014-06-02     3     3
```

Set the filter and make values in the `column_to_be_updated` satisfying the filter equal to 0.

```
mask = (df1['zick']>= 2) & (df1['zick'] < 4)
df1.loc[(mask & (df1['eins'].isnull())), 'eins'] = 0
print df1

            zick  zack  eins
2014-06-01     1     1   NaN
2014-06-01     2     2     0
2014-06-02     3     3     0
2014-06-02     3     3     0
```

Update `inplace` your df1 with df2 values (only values equal to 0 will be updated):

```
df1.update(df2, filter_func=lambda x: x == 0)
print df1

            zick  zack  eins
2014-06-01     1     1   NaN
2014-06-01     2     2     2
2014-06-02     3     3     3
2014-06-02     3     3     3
```

Now if you want to change the filter and do the update again it will not change previously updated values:

```
mask = (df1['zick']>= 1) & (df1['zick'] == 1)
df1.loc[(mask & (df1['eins'].isnull())), 'eins'] = 0
print df1

            zick  zack  eins
2014-06-01     1     1     0
2014-06-01     2     2     2
2014-06-02     3     3     3
2014-06-02     3     3     3

df1.update(df2, filter_func=lambda x: x == 0)
print df1

            zick  zack  eins
2014-06-01     1     1     2
2014-06-01     2     2     2
2014-06-02     3     3     3
2014-06-02     3     3     3
```

Comment: Yes, this is the output I want to have. However, I want to apply this procedure several times with different filter criteria to df1. Using the above code snippet would overwrite older inserted values in 'eins' everytime with NaN. Therefor I look for joining only those rows of df1, which fulfill the filter criteria.

Comment: Aha, this is changing the game somewhat... I hope this is not a [`XY Problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) :-) Anyway, I have updated the answer to reflect this information.